# rotating image on clicking a button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have seen some jquery plugin taht can rotate image continuously. I want that that effect by clicking a button. The image should be rotate continuously like a wheel. The button will work like a on-off switch. Here is the idea:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('on')){
    $('image').stopRotate();
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
  }
  else{
    $('image').startRotate();
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
  }
})
```

Comment: Why are you adding/removing classes when you start/stop your rotate function? What's the question here?

Comment: I want to use the button as a toggle handler for rotating image. It will start and stop the animation (rotating wheel). The question is how do I do the whole process.This is a plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/. but I cannot modify it to solve my purpose.

Comment: I sorted out a solution. thanks

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/?